# Trying to understand this function as value

Tags: javascript

I got this code from the Headfirst Javascript book. I changed the function names to be clearer.  I'm trying to wrap my head around this.

I assigned add to the function outer with a number.  That number remains for some reason - returns a reference to inner with n = num (which returns the added values?

Anytime I change outers n value, the inner will use that new value?
I believe I'm right on that.  Is there anywhere I can read more about it? See better examples?  Or can anyone explain this better?

```js
function outer(n) {
 var inner = function(x) { //or x = 0
   return n + (x || 0); //added default 0 for testing to prevent NaN
  }
  return inner;
}
var num = 2;
var add = outer(num);
console.log(`Adding 2 to num(${num}): ${add(2)}`);

add = outer(5);
console.log(add());
console.log(add(2));
```

Comment: What is your **actual** question? **Re-define** your **real** question and try again. Aswell you're example is **flawed** - theres no function called `add2()`

Comment: I think the words you are looking for are *partial application*  and *currying*. Using these terms you should be able to find explanations online

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In JavaScript, functions can act as regular data. If you are OK with the idea of passing a number or string around, then passing a function around is no different. This allows you the ability to do some very cool and powerful things.

Here, instead of the `add` function simply giving you your numeric answer, it's giving you back a function with your number embedded into it. This means that `add` doesn't really add anything, `add` is a function for creating functions (similar to the idea of a "Factory" in class based programming).

Changing the names may make things easier:

```
function createAddFunction(numberThatWillBeHardWiredIntoReturnedFunction) {
    var resultingFunction= function(x) { //or x = 0
    return numberThatWillBeHardWiredIntoReturnedFunction + (x || 0); 
  }
  return resultingFunction;
}
var num = 2;

// This will cause add to be a function that is hard-wired to add 2 to another number
var add = createAddFunction(num);  
console.log(`Adding 2 to num(${num}): ${add(2)}`);

// This will cause add to be a function that is hard-wired to add 5 to another number
add = createAddFunction(5);
console.log(add());
console.log(add(2));
```

Comment: Yup the names totally make a difference.  In the book it was simply a challenge.  As I typed it out it started to make sense.  So I renamed the functions to outer/inner.  Also, with the advice from a few others here, I'll read up on currying.  I like your answer though!

Answer (score 1):

Let's rename the functions to make it even clearer.  The outer function takes a parameter and uses it to create a new function.  This new function is returned for future use.

```js
function createFunctionThatAdds(n){
  var adds_n = function(x) { return n + (x || 0); };
  return adds_n;
}

var adds_2 = createFunctionThatAdds(2);
var adds_5 = createFunctionThatAdds(5);

console.log(adds_2(10));
console.log(adds_5(10));
```

Comment: So, this 'technique' pretty much creates functions.  Is there a word for it (so i could read about it)?

Comment: Thats no real `technique` you simply return a function for further use to prevent having **redundant** code (because you would have to define `add2()` and `add5()` and the plus operation twice.)

Comment: @noisypixy Good resource! And I thought closures were simply functions within functions.

Answer (score 1):

The technique used is called `currying`. It's part of functional javascript.

You can read more about it [here](https://www.sitepoint.com/currying-in-functional-javascript/).

The idea behind it is that you can use a function to generate another function, which you can use further in your code.

Currying is made possible, because of a [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures).

There are a lot of libraries that are built based on that principe, for example [Ramda](http://ramdajs.com/docs/).